# How to Write Ant Scripts?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ant, jakarta-ee

Can anyone tell me how to write Ant script (if i want to create my own) mean is there any kind of tutorial available?

Eclipse/Netbeans provide Ant script automatically but can it be possible to edit and customize them as per requirement? If yes then how to do this and how to customize the workspace which is provided by IDE.

Edit: Is there any good book available for ANT? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: You do not need to write Ant scripts to get deployment working in Eclipse, but why do you want to switch to Eclipse when NetBeans works well for you? More people use Eclipse (me too), that is true, but NetBeans is also quite popular, and unless Eclipse is mandated for your team, why change your tooling and pay the loss in productivity this will initially cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers:

- Window > Preferences > Server - configure target server runtimes
- right-click project > Properties > Java Build Path - lets you add additional jars and libraries. Eclipse offers you a pre-configured library for web development
- As Abdel said, get the Web Tools Platform (WTP) plugin
- Window > Show View > Servers - opens the servers panel, where you can start/stop a server and manage deployed applications.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Eclipse are you using? Like Netbeans Eclipse also has the feature of automated build and deploy. You need not write any Ant script. Check if you are using Eclipse for Java EE developer and Web Tools Platform.
 Regards,
Abdel Olakara

Comment: Hi Abdel,

Could u pls suggest me which version I should use and from where I can download this?

Thanks

Comment: You can download the latest version from http://eclipse.org/.. From different Eclipse packages.. you will have to download the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers". It is the first package option :)